# Android Fragment transaction not happening after global layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to have an Activity that can slide between two fragments up and down with a button in the handle between them. To do this I have two FrameLayout containers, one is declared in XML with a weight 1 inside a Linear layout, the button is then a fixed height after the container which looks like this:

[image]

The red part is the container for the first fragment. I then want to programatically add another fragment container for fragment two underneath the screen which is exactly the same height as the measured fragment container one. So I use:

```
    containerAdmin.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new     ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            fragmentHeight = containerAdmin.getHeight();
            instantiateFragments();
        }
    });
```

This works fine, I then capture the touch event of the activity and move y values of all containers on the touch event so that the user can scroll these containers up as shown in this image :

[image]

This works beautifully and as you can see the blue container for fragment two is shown and it is the correct height. Now that I have both containers (FrameLayout)'s which are the right size and placed correctly, I add the fragments using a FragmentTransaction like so:

```
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.admin_container, new AdminFragment());
        transaction.add(R.id.client_container, new ClientFragment());
        transaction.commit();
```

To my surprise, the second FrameLayout container is successful and gets the fragment as expected, but the first container (the one which I have measured with on global layout) is not there. I have even pulled an XML UI spec from ADM and inspected the UI hierarchy, That first  fragment  "AdminFragment" does not exist at all yet the "ClientFragment" is rendered correctly. I have coloured the containers to make sure that they are in fact inflated correctly and visible. I have even tried to call

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

after the transaction with no success. Any ideas? Let me know if I can elaborate on the issue further or if you think I should take a different approach.

Comment: I have managed to fix it temporarily, by simply removing then re adding the first container. I would really love to find out why the fragment would not transact into that container until I do so. Any help would be appreciated.